# Wordpress - using php to redirect to a different page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a form that when submitted, adds data to a mysql database and redirects to a success page.

I added this code to the bottom of my functions.php file:

```
add_action('init', 'form_submit');
function form_submit(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['form_sub']))
    {
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $age= $_POST['age'];
        $wpdb->insert( 
    'mytable', 
    array( 
        'name' => $name, 
        'age' => $age
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s' 
    ) 
    );
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and added a form to my page that calls this function when submit is clicked.

When I try this, the data is added to the mysql database, but the redirect doesn't seem to work.  Instead of going to google.com, it adds this to the top of the page:

> Object Moved 
>   This document may be found here

Where here is a link to google.com.  Any idea on how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably sending the redirect header too late (after the page is rendered).

Check this out: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-page-redirect

You can try to put out a javascript redirect if you can't get the header() or wp_redirect() out early enough.